# What is 'None' that shows up in the filesystem in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, filesystem

```
$ df -h

S.ficheros     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en 
/dev/sda5         36G    11G   23G  33% / 
none             4,0K      0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             1,5G   4,0K  1,5G   1% /dev 
tmpfs            296M   1,1M  295M   1% /run 
none             5,0M      0  5,0M   0% /run/lock 
none             1,5G    80K  1,5G   1% /run/shm 
none             100M    40K  100M   1% /run/user
```

I do not understand none file system.

which is none filesystem?

I have something wrong?

Comment: using the `-T` flag shows the type of fs too, the "none" ones are all tmpfs as Rinzwind knows. As to why the Filesystem column is a mix of type, or device, or none or sometimes tmpfs...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"none" means it is a temporarily mounted filesystem storage (created by the kernel). The storage does not happen on your hard disk drive but happens in memory (or in the swap space).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong. I have the same.

```
/dev/sdb2       219G   19G  190G   9% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7,8G  8,0K  7,8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  1,4M  1,6G   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            7,9G   65M  7,8G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   60K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       197M  3,4M  194M   2% /boot/efi
```